# moment is not defined angular moment picker

Tags: angularjs, angular-daterangepicker

I have used 'Angular-Moment-Picker' for implementig date Picker with Angular1.6 and facing console error 'Moment is not defined' after importing required Module.

Official website for Angular-Moment-Picker: https://indrimuska.github.io/angular-moment-picker/

**Error:**

[image]

I have added module as per below. 
1. I have installed 'Angular-Moment-picker' and Moment using NPM iNSTALL.
2. included both modules in app.module.js file.

```
import momentPicker from 'angular-moment-picker';
import * as moment from 'moment/min/moment-with-locales';
```

Also,

```
const app = angular
    .module('app', [
        ...
        moment,
        momentPicker,
       ...
    ])...
```

Now, I am facing this error in console.

Also, I have also tried adding few things inside 'webpack-config.js' file  but there is no luck on it.

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            moment: 'moment',
        }),
```

Not only that, I have also tried many things but still no luck.

It would be great, if some can help me on it.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: you only need `angular.module('myApp', ['moment-picker'])` (with quotes 
 around the injected module)

Comment: It's angular 1.6 apps.. hence, we have different way to include the module. Hence, this is not applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I am able to resolve this issue by manually including the 'Angular-Moment-Picker' JS file and linked to `index.js` file.

**app.module.js**

```js
import './angular-moment-picker.min';
import './moment-with-`enter code here`locales';
import './angular-moment-picker.css';

angular
    .module('app', [
...
               'moment-picker',
....
    ])
```

Also added file details inside `index.html`

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/load/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/load/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/load/angular-moment-picker.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks for all for your support and help on it.